# Rails nested form, calulate value from nested items during

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, before-save

I am new to rails and am working on one of my first rails projects, it is an invoice app with nested line items within the invoice form. I want to calculate the total invoice before I save the invoice. I get it to save nicely if just added items during the save process, but it doesn't calulate the total correctly if one of the nested line items is tagged to be deleted. I would have to go back in and save again to get the correct total billed amount.

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :job_name, :items_attributes, :tax1, :tax2, :subtotal

  before_save :calculate_totals


  has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, allow_destroy: true

  private

  def calculate_totals
    self.subtotal = 0

    self.items.each do |i|
      self.subtotal = self.subtotal + (i.quantity * i.cost_per)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm note sure how this differs from params but the problem item record is listed in the requested paramaters with :_destroy = true

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"+OqRa7vRa1CKPMCdBrjhvU6jzMH1zQ=",
 "invoice"=>{"client_id"=>"1",
 "job_name"=>"dsdsadsad",
 "items_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"jhksadhshdkjhkjdh",
 "quantity"=>"1",
 "cost_per"=>"50.0",
 "id"=>"21",
 "_destroy"=>"false"},
 "1"=>{"name"=>"delete this one",
 "quantity"=>"1",
 "cost_per"=>"10.0",
 "id"=>"24",
 "_destroy"=>"true"}}},
 "commit"=>"Update Invoice",
 "id"=>"8"}
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :job_name, :items_attributes, :tax1, :tax2, :subtotal

  before_save :calculate_totals


  has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, allow_destroy: true

  private
    def calculate_totals
      self.subtotal = 0

      self.items.each do |i|
        unless i.marked_for_destruction?
          self.subtotal += (i.quantity * i.cost_per)
        end
      end

end
```

The key is the method marked_for_destruction? In this case I was checking for items that weren't marked for destroy. Here's the link to the rails api that explains it: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Thanks
Steve

Comment: Thank you for writing this solution, it helped me solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
params[:invoice][:items_attributes].each do |i|
  self.subtotal = self.subtotal + (i[:quantity].to_f * i[:cost_per].to_f) unless i['_destroy'] == 'true'
end
```

Comment: when I tried this I got undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Invoice:0x00000103d0b9d0>, are params available in the model? I can add raise params.inspect right before the update_attributes is called and it pulls the right value, if add raise the same item with in the calulate_totals methods I get the same error as above

Answer (score 0):

You have calculated items **before `Invoice` was saved**, so it calculated items destroyed too, as in API document has guide:

> Note that the model will not be destroyed until the parent is saved.

So you just need change `before_save` to `after_save`, it will works.

Comment: hey Kien, I tried this and it never updates the subtotals, even if none of the records are tagged for detstroy. Was I supposed to move this after_save to the items model?

Comment: Are you means it updates on browser when invoice was not saved? after invoice is saved, does it calculate right subtotals?

Comment: it wasn't updating the subtotals at all

Comment: I think you should call calculate_totals method in Invoice controller after invoice created, because that time invoice already know all about its items. Currently, your private method has no way to know which items are deleted on browser. Maybe you need change it to protected.